# Netbeans GUI not showing up objects

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, calculator, builder

for some reason my GUI program in netbeans doesn 't work properly;
I try to make a program that says how much time it takes before something is downloaded, so I have an spinner for how much kb/mb/gb is being transfert per second, a spinner for the already done progress and a spinner for the target kb/gb/mb. here is my code

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package GUI;

import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 *
 * @author Jari
 */
public class InternetSpeed extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form InternetSpeed
     */
    public InternetSpeed() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        spinnerComboSpeed = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        comboUnitSpeed = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        comboTarget = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Progress = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        completed = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        comboCompleted = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        completedSpinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        calcButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        totLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        comboUnitSpeed.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "KB", "MB", "GB" }));

        jLabel1.setText("Snelheid per seconde");

        comboTarget.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "KB", "MB", "GB" }));

        jLabel2.setText("te behalen volume");

        completed.setText("Momenteel behaald");

        comboCompleted.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "KB", "MB", "GB" }));
        comboCompleted.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                comboCompletedActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        calcButton.setText("Bereken");
        calcButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                calcButtonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        totLabel.setText("0s");
        totLabel.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                totLabelPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(calcButton)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(Progress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                    .addComponent(completed))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(spinnerComboSpeed)
                                    .addComponent(completedSpinner))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(comboUnitSpeed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(comboTarget, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(comboCompleted, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(totLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(130, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(spinnerComboSpeed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(comboUnitSpeed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(completed)
                    .addComponent(comboCompleted, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(completedSpinner, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(comboTarget, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(totLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Progress, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(calcButton)
                .addContainerGap(43, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        calcButton.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(calcButton);
        totLabel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(calcButton);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void comboCompletedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    private void calcButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int speed = 0, comp = 0, tot= 0;
        switch ((char) comboUnitSpeed.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case '0':
                speed = (int) spinnerComboSpeed.getValue() * 1;
            case '1':
                speed = (int) spinnerComboSpeed.getValue() * 1000;
            case '2':
                speed = (int) spinnerComboSpeed.getValue() * 1000000;
        }
        switch ((char) comboCompleted.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case '0':
                comp = (int) completedSpinner.getValue() * 1;
            case '1':
                comp = (int) completedSpinner.getValue() * 1000;
            case '2':
                comp = (int) completedSpinner.getValue() * 1000000;
        }
        switch ((char) comboTarget.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case '0':
                tot = (int) jSpinner1.getValue() * 1;
            case '1':
                tot = (int) jSpinner1.getValue() * 1000;
            case '2':
                tot = (int) jSpinner1.getValue() * 1000000;
        }
        int totaal = tot - comp;
        BigInteger sp = BigInteger.valueOf(speed);
        BigInteger t = BigInteger.valueOf(totaal);
        BigInteger u = t.gcd(sp);

        int uit = u.intValue();
        totLabel.setText(uit+"s");
    }                                       

    private void totLabelPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar Progress;
    private javax.swing.JButton calcButton;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox comboCompleted;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox comboTarget;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox comboUnitSpeed;
    private javax.swing.JLabel completed;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner completedSpinner;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner spinnerComboSpeed;
    private javax.swing.JLabel totLabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put all your GUI in a panel, then type:

```
int uit = u.intValue();
totLabel.setText(uit+"s");
panel1.repaint();
```

I am hoping it will help you.